# getDisplayOriginatingAddress returns sender name instead of phone number

Tags: android, sms, listener

I have problem getting incoming sms phone number, when using getDisplayOriginatingAddress or getOriginatingAddress, I only got sender name like "NXSMS" instead of the phone number (digit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the documentation, the **getDisplayOriginatingAddress()** method returns the phone number if the SMS was sent from a regular phone, it returns an email or another name like "NXSMS" if the SMS was sent from the email gateway.